# Cost Effectiveness of Amazon AWS Redshift vs Amazon AWS ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, amazon-redshift

I have a use case where I have to collect 1k events/sec. They have to queryable but read queries are not too high. For eg. I have an event like this:

{

id: " 1,

"type" : "start",

"publisher": " ",

"company": " ",

}

I wanna be able to query over publisher, company, type, id etc. I don't need full text search or so. Essentially I am using ElasticSearch as a NoSQL database but instead of just querying with the key, I want to query by a variety of columns. I was wondering how Redshift will compare with this. The total data size would be 3-4 TB.

Comment: Do you also have the need to store this data long term (say beyond 1 day) ?

Comment: I need it for at least a year

Comment: have you considered Athena?

Comment: @JonScott Yes, I need the data to be accessible via the web interface. So Athena won't do.

Comment: What is wrong with the Athena web interface vs the redshift one? I don't understand your point.

Comment: I don't believe that Athena can be queried as quickly as ElasticSearch. Also data in Athena has to be partitioned by a variable like timestamp etc. It isn't fliexible for querying with other elements like publisher, company etc